# Node.js Sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two models User and Products with the relation One-many.
I would like to build up REST APi based on that but how would it be possible to retrieve the data from DB using ORM when hittig the end point like that user/3/product/1 ?

Relation:

```
User.hasMany(Product);
```

Product.belongsTo(User, { constraints: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
// i know cascade is not pretty safe

Controller:

```
const getProduct = (req, res, next) => {
```

const { userId, productId } = req.params;
// I actually mean how Would it be possible to retrieve from DB this particular product when hitting url user/3/product/1?

}

Thank You very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the url `user/3/product/1` you need to get a certain product that belongs to a certain user. So the start point is `Product` model and the question is what conditions you should indicate to get the correct product.

```js
const { userId, productId } = req.params; 
const product = await Product.findOne({
  where: {
   userId, 
   id: productId
  }
})
```

That way you will restrict a client that requests a product from indicating incorrect pair of a user id and a product id.